# How to get a data Snapshot from Firebase once and only once (using C#)?

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working with Unity, using C#, and need to get a snapshot at the beggining of the scene. But I need to get the snapshot **once and only once**.
So far, all exemples I found use some sort of event listener to get the snapshot, and it means that the snapshot can be overwritten by some event.
After I created the event listener (following a tutorial), I worked around the problem with an if-statement.

The code I'm using:

```
DataSnapshot dbSnapshot; // <-- the snapshot I need to use later

void Start(){
    StartListener();
    // Other stuff happens...
}

protected void StartListener() {
    dbRoot.ValueChanged += (
    object sender2, ValueChangedEventArgs e2) => {
        if (e2.DatabaseError != null) {
            Debug.LogError(e2.DatabaseError.Message);
            return;
        }
        Debug.Log("ValueChangedEventArgs");
        if (e2.Snapshot != null || e2.Snapshot.Value != null){
            if (dbSnapshot == null){
            //  This happens once, and prevents the dbSnapshot from being overwritten
                dbSnapshot = e2.Snapshot;
            }
        }
    };
}
```

It seems to work but I would like to know if it's possible to get the snapshot without an event listener or, at least, if there is a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 1):

Bellow example how i get leaderboard, this get data only one.

```
FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance
           .GetReference("Leaders").OrderByChild("Score")
           .GetValueAsync().ContinueWith(task =>
           {
               if (task.IsFaulted)
               {
                   Debug.LogError("Get faulted");
                   return;
               }
               if (task.Result != null && task.Result.ChildrenCount > 0)
               {
                   Debug.Log("Get data success!");
                   ...
               }
           });
```

Comment: Thanks, @TrungBui. I think I came across this bit of code before. What isn't clear for me is how, in this case, I would set the value for the "DataSnapshot dbSnapshot" variable (the one I declared right at the start of the code). I'm filling in for the "database guy" so everything related to Firebase is still kind of arcane to me.

Comment: I'm not sure understand your question. You want to set the value dbSnapshot variable on the firebase? Just used SetRawJsonValueAsync like:  FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Leaders").Child("User").Child(user id).SetRawJsonValueAsync(userData).ContinueWith(task => ... )